# apache poi indexoutofbound exception

Tags: java, apache-poi

- Excel File (test1.xlsx)
  Name     Gender     Age     Resign Date
  Ali              M           20
  Abu            M          25
  Siti             F           30
- Code

  ```
  public class ReadExcel {

  public static ArrayList<String> record;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

   //---Read file---
  FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("test1.xlsx");
  XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(in);
  XSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
  XSSFRow row;
  Cell cell;

  Iterator<Row> rowIterator = spreadsheet.iterator();

  while(rowIterator.hasNext()){
      record = new ArrayList<String>();
      row = (XSSFRow)rowIterator.next();

      if(row.getRowNum()==0) {
          continue;
      }

       for(int k = 0; k < row.getLastCellNum();k++){
          cell = row.getCell(k, Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
      }

      Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

      while(cellIterator.hasNext()){
              cell = cellIterator.next();
              cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING); 

              switch(cell.getCellType()){
                  case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                      record.add(cell.getStringCellValue());
                      System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue());
                      break;
                  case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                      Double value = cell.getNumericCellValue();
                      Long longValue = value.longValue();

                      record.add(Double.toString(cell.getNumericCellValue()));
                      System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                      break;
              }
          }   
          System.out.println();

          String name = record.get(0);
          String gender = record.get(1);
          String age = record.get(2);
          String dateLeave = record.get(3);  //[ERROR]

          System.out.println(name + gender + age + dateLeave);
          }
      }
  }
  ```

However, from my above program, I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 3
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
at ibguobform.ReadExcel.main(ReadExcel.java:66)
Java Result: 1
```

What is the errors that I made?

Comment: Have you debugged this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is trying to reference the fourth element of a collection that has only three elements:

```
record.get(3)
```

Since there's only three elements, trying to reference the fourth one produces an error.

**Why are there only three elements?**

Well, look at the data:

```
Ali     M     20
Abu     M     25
Siti    F     30
```

Three elements per line.

What appears to be happening is the code is dynamically checking for the last "element":

```
for(int k = 0; k < row.getLastCellNum(); k++){
    cell = row.getCell(k, Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
}
```

It would seem that `row.getLastCellNum()` is telling the code that there are only three cells.  (Because, well, there are only three cells with data in them.)  If the fourth cell is valid even when there's no data, explicitly note that in the code by always using four elements:

```
for(int k = 0; k < 4; k++){
    cell = row.getCell(k, Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
}
```